# Issues trying to image ISO to USB file with sudo dd command

Tags: usb, iso-image

I’m trying to image the Kali ISO to a USB and I’ve followed these instructions:

- Plug in your USB device to your Apple computer’s USB port.
- Verify the device path of your USB storage with diskutil list.
- Unmount the drive (note, in this example, the USB stick is /dev/disk4):

  > diskutil unmount /dev/disk4
- Proceed to (carefully!) image the Kali ISO file on the USB device:

  > sudo dd if=kali-linux-*.iso of=/dev/disk4 bs=1m

But terminal keeps returning:

> dd: kali-linux-*.iso: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

DD doesn't understand wildcards.

Just enter full name of your ISO (if=`full path + full name`)

Comment: Thanks man, literally just figured it out before you replied with trial and error.